# Wrong images by fast scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've an app that provides product information. The information (including images) come from the internet.

It works okay, but when I scroll fast I'll see the wrong picture until the correct one has loaded. How can I show a blank UIImage until the image is loaded when the user is scrolling fast?

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (Cell == nil) {
        Cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    NSString *titeltext = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
    NSString *oudprijstext = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"prijsoud"];
    NSString *nieuwprijstext = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"prijsnieuw"];
    NSString *tijdtext = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"verloopt"];
    NSString *plaatjetext = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"thumb"];
    NSString *linktext = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSString *buttontext = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"knop"];
    NSString *aanbiedertext = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"logo"];

    plaatjetext = [plaatjetext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<![CDATA[" withString:@""];
    plaatjetext = [plaatjetext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]]>" withString:@""];
    plaatjetext = [plaatjetext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    plaatjetext = [plaatjetext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    aanbiedertext = [aanbiedertext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<![CDATA[" withString:@""];
    aanbiedertext = [aanbiedertext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]]>" withString:@""];
    aanbiedertext = [aanbiedertext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    aanbiedertext = [aanbiedertext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    UIFont *titelfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TitilliumWeb-SemiBold" size:12];
    UIFont *oudfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TitilliumWeb-Light" size:12];
    UIFont *buttonfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TitilliumWeb-SemiBold" size:15];

    [Cell.titel setText:titeltext];
    Cell.titel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    Cell.titel.numberOfLines = 2;
    Cell.titel.font = titelfont;
    [Cell.tijd setText:tijdtext];
    Cell.tijd.font = titelfont;
    [Cell.knop setText:buttontext];
    [Cell.knop setFont:buttonfont];
    [Cell.prijsnieuw setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"€ %@", nieuwprijstext]];
    Cell.prijsnieuw.font = titelfont;
    [Cell.prijsoud setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"€ %@", oudprijstext]];
    Cell.prijsoud.font = oudfont;

    UIImage *cachedImage = [self.imageCache objectForKey:plaatjetext];
    if (cachedImage)
    {
        Cell.plaatje.image = cachedImage;
    }
    else
    {
        // you'll want to initialize the image with some blank image as a placeholder

        //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blankthumbnail.png"];

        // now download in the image in the background

        [self.imageDownloadingQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

            NSURL *imageUrl   = [NSURL URLWithString:plaatjetext];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
            UIImage *image    = nil;
            if (imageData)
                image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            if (image)
            {
                // add the image to your cache

                [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:plaatjetext];

                // finally, update the user interface in the main queue

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    // make sure the cell is still visible

                    UITableViewCell *updateCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    if (updateCell)
                        Cell.plaatje.image = image;
                }];
            }
        }];
    }

    UIImage *cachedImage2 = [self.imageCache2 objectForKey:aanbiedertext];
    if (cachedImage2)
    {
        Cell.aanbieder.image = cachedImage2;
    }
    else
    {
        // you'll want to initialize the image with some blank image as a placeholder

        //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blankthumbnail.png"];

        // now download in the image in the background

        [self.imageDownloadingQueue2 addOperationWithBlock:^{

            NSURL *imageUrl2   = [NSURL URLWithString:aanbiedertext];
            NSData *imageData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl2];
            UIImage *image2    = nil;
            if (imageData2)
                image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];

            if (image2)
            {
                // add the image to your cache

                [self.imageCache2 setObject:image2 forKey:aanbiedertext];

                // finally, update the user interface in the main queue

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    // make sure the cell is still visible

                    UITableViewCell *updateCell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    if (updateCell2)
                        Cell.aanbieder.image = image2;
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
    //Cell.plaatje.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:plaatjetext]]];
    //Cell.aanbieder.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aanbiedertext]]];

    return Cell;
}
```

Please help me with instruction and/or sample code.
Thanks in advance! :)

Rick

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to tackle the other end of the problem? Maybe try to figure out why the incorrect picture is being displayed in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You commented out the code that was supposed to do that:

```
    // you'll want to initialize the image with some blank image as a placeholder

    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blankthumbnail.png"];
```

Enable it back and you should be good. In your custom cell I think you would need to apply this to `Cell.plaatje.image` and `Cell.aanbieder.image`.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I don't saw that!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to implement `prepareForReuse` in your `CustomCell` class:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.plaatje.image = nil;
}
```